# Why not travel back in time earlier?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-horror-story

In the recent season of *American Horror Story - Apocalypse*, we learn that the witches can travel back in time (well, one special witch can anyway). Why did they wait until after everyone died to go back? Why not just go back as soon as Madison came back from hell house with information on Michael?

I don't recall an explanation being given.